# How to limit daily-usage even if user sets his clock back?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have an IOS app that needs to track duration of free usage per day. Once it crosses a threshold, the user would have to purchase the app or wait for the next day to unlock his free-usage minutes for that day.

Is there a native way to detect if the user has set his clock back? Assume there is no Internet connection to sync with a time server

Comment: I'd say try storing a value of time remaining for this day in NSUserDefaults.
And then change it every minute and if the value = 0 then disable the app till the date changes. But then if he changes the date the time will be reset I guess.

Comment: Before doing this, you may want to check with Apple, that they won't reject your app as a consequence.

Comment: @Jeremy, why would Apple have a problem with what Novarg suggested?

Comment: I suspect this wouldn't pass Apple's requirements for trial versions.

Comment: Apple discourages feature-locking, e.g. a tab which remains disabled till the app is purchased. What I am trying to do here is to allow the user enjoy the full featured app for an hour a day. I was thinking this might be okay with App store.

Comment: @SaptarshiBiswas: I had a look at Apple's acceptance guidelines (actually they were more like rejection guidelines) and while there were no rejection criteria for this specific functionality, they do ban time limited apps i.e. apps that expire after a certain date.  They might decide that this is another new reason to ban an app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`UIApplicationDelegate` can get the following method called on significant time changes:

```
- (void)applicationSignificantTimeChange:(UIApplication *)application
```

You can try that one. From my point of view, I'd recommend to check current date on every application launch or willBecomeActive and store those dates as list somewhere securely. If current date is different from the last date, add it to your list. If list has more than 30 items (or how many you need) disable trial functionality.

Comment: good answer, but this only gets called ***if*** the application is running... if the cheating user quits the app, resets the clock back and then restarts, they still get their free usage.

Comment: anyway, my proposal with checking a date with last known - should work

Comment: Hi @Denis, I like +1 your answer. However I was trying to implement one-hour-per-day of free usage, not a 30-day trial. Currently my plan involves comparing the current vs last-seen latest date to detect if the user has set back his clock. He can always set his clock forward to beat the system.

Comment: it can be a good punishment for user to set-back time every hour =)