# What is the best approach to handle trial version apps?

Tags: ios, registration

I am developing an application where the user can use the app without registering for 14 days. After which he must register (not any payment) to continue using the app.

The approach I am using now is to store the first launch date into the user defaults, and compare it with the current date on every successive launches. This approach will fail if the user sets back the clock to avoid being have to register.

My question is similar to the following question, [How to limit daily-usage even if user sets his clock back?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8356670/how-to-limit-daily-usage-even-if-user-sets-his-clock-back), but I am not sure that will help me.

Is there any other better approach?

Comment: I suppose the app could hit a web service to get the time, but how many users do you think will care/be savvy enough to do this?

Comment: You could store the cummulative time the app has been running, saving it everytine your app will terminate or go to the background. It won't give you 14 days straight from the first run, but a limit on 'hours used'.

Comment: If you use the method outlined in the linked question's answer, you could compare the times and actually detect the clock exploit, and maybe throw up a warning message.

Comment: Does signing up to your service cost money? Is this app a free trial of some external paid service?

Answer (score 5):

I believe these trail apps are not entertained by Apple read Apple guidelines

**2.9 Apps that are "beta", "demo", "trial", or "test" versions will be rejected**

Answer (score 1):

I think this can help.

Define a list of 14 days and store them in the user defaults.
The first day is the installation date and the others are the next 13 days.
These are the only days allowed to use your application. If the user sets the date prior to your first day, it will be out of the allowed range.
This does not prevent setting the date to any date in range. To avoid it, store the usage minutes for each day and check for a reasonable maximun usage per day.

To avoid the user reinstalling the app, store some data in the keychain to keep a record of the installation and total free usage.