# How do I set an hourly limit on a UIButton's action?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, nstimer

In my app, I would like to limit the amount of times a specific UIButton (which is connected to an action method) can be pressed to 500 times per hour. Each time this button is clicked, a virtual point is earned, and I would like to limit the amount of points a user can earn to 500/hour.

When the 500 point limit is reached, I want to replace the button with a message (a UILabel) that tells the user that he/she must wait "0:XX" minutes.

I am visualizing something along the lines of how Mafia Wars limits users.

I have found this [similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8356670/how-to-limit-daily-usage-even-if-user-sets-his-clock-back) but it does not explain what I specifically want.

Comment: Who's really going to tap a button 500 times in one hour if its not a shooter or rhythm game or similar? Make something more interesting.

Answer (score 2):

How about to make a `Array` to store your `button click` history

When you click the button , then get the clicks `Time` , and add it into the `history array`

you can check the `Time` which index of the array is 500 before the current `Time`(if there is no more than 500 , it means use should not wait).

And calc the duration between the `Current Time` and the `500 Before Time`

If the `duration >= 1hour` , do nothing
;Else the `duration < 1hour` , make the button enable , and retrun (1hour - duration) , the return duration is user must wait

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is to have an `NSDate` variable, and when the button is pressed, set it to `[NSDate date]` (if you want it to be an hour since the first press, only set it if clicks==0)

Then you will want an NSTimer that loops ever few seconds or however accurate you want it to be and checks if `[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:firstDate]>3600`, which would then reset the number of clicks.

Comment: You would also want to store this date in NSUserPreferences or in some file and retrieve it when the app opens so they can't cheat by closing and re-opening the app!

Answer (score 0):

As already suggested I would buld a solution on `NSDate *now = [NSDate date];`

On every button click, within the action method, you would create a date object like this and add it to an array (the array is a class property or class internal variable).

```
NSMutableArray *clicksOf60Minutes;  // can be initialized with alloc/initWithCapacity:501;
```

Capacity could well be 550 or so. Do some test and go for an appropriate value. It is rather a question of performance and memory management. Your code will work regardless what value you choose for initialization.

After adding one (you add one anyway for future evaluations) then you delete all objectc from the array that are older than 60 minutes.

```
do {
  [clicksOf60Minutes removeObjectAtIndex:0];
} while ([[clicksOf60Minutes removeObjectAtIndex:0]  timeIntervalSinceDate:firstDate]>3600]);
```

Don't shout at me if `do/while` is the wrong loop and `while` is better. It should be the one that evaluates the condition first and then performs the loop's body only if the condition was true upfront. If I am not much mistaken this is the right one. Please double check that. 
Once that is done your array consists of those clicking moments only which did occur during the past 60 minutes. Now check for its number.

```
if ([clicksOf60Minutes count] > 500) {
  // add points
} else {
  // show altert 
}
```